# Use Javascript and JSON.parse to parse through multidimentional array

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, multidimensional-array

I have the following code, and for a simple array, it works just fine, but now when using a more complex multidimensional array of data, I cant seem to pull the right values.  The JSON that I'm given is as follows:

```
{
  "kind": "tasks",
  "data": [
{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "TEST NAME 1",
  "status": "Active",
  "importance": "Normal",
  "createdDate": "2016-09-13T15:25:57Z",
  "updatedDate": "2016-09-13T15:25:57Z",
  "dates": {
    "type": "Planned",
    "duration": 43200,
    "start": "2018-10-10T09:00:00",
    "due": "2019-02-12T17:00:00"
  },
  "scope": "WsTask",
  "priority": "1a0448008000000000005000"
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "title": "TEST NAME 2",
  "status": "Active",
  "importance": "Normal",
  "createdDate": "2018-10-10T19:32:32Z",
  "updatedDate": "2018-12-17T16:46:06Z",
  "dates": {
    "type": "Planned",
    "duration": 43200,
    "start": "2018-10-11T09:00:00",
    "due": "2019-02-13T17:00:00"
  },
  "scope": "WsTask",
  "priority": "5bfa68008000000000003c00"
}
  ]
}
```

The code I am using is as follows:

```
const app = document.getElementById('root');
const logo = document.createElement('img');

const container = document.createElement('div');
container.setAttribute('class', 'container');

app.appendChild(logo);
app.appendChild(container);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'BEARER ' + 'PRIVATETOKEN');
request.open('GET', 'PRIVATEADDRESS', true);

request.onload = function () {

  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var testdata = JSON.parse(this.response);

  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    testdata.forEach(tasks => {
      const card = document.createElement('div');
      card.setAttribute('class', 'card');

      const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
      h1.textContent = tasks.title;

      container.appendChild(card);
      card.appendChild(h1);
    });
  } else {
    const errorMessage = document.createElement('marquee');
    errorMessage.textContent = 'Gah';
    app.appendChild(errorMessage);
  }
}

request.send();
```

Once I get a working sample, I can extend it to use other data, but for now, I am just needing help calling each Title from the data array.

Comment: You should provide an example that demonstrates how and where you `can't seem to pull the right values`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `testdata` contains the JSON in your first code block, `testdata` is not an array. It is an object with a `data` property that is an array. So you would need something like below (calling forEach on `testdata.data` instead of `testdata`).

```
testdata.data.forEach(tasks => {
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.setAttribute('class', 'card');

    const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.textContent = tasks.title;

    container.appendChild(card);
    card.appendChild(h1);
});
```

Here's a snippet showing a fully working example:

```js
const testdata = {
  "kind": "tasks",
  "data": [
{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "TEST NAME 1",
  "status": "Active",
  "importance": "Normal",
  "createdDate": "2016-09-13T15:25:57Z",
  "updatedDate": "2016-09-13T15:25:57Z",
  "dates": {
    "type": "Planned",
    "duration": 43200,
    "start": "2018-10-10T09:00:00",
    "due": "2019-02-12T17:00:00"
  },
  "scope": "WsTask",
  "priority": "1a0448008000000000005000"
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "title": "TEST NAME 2",
  "status": "Active",
  "importance": "Normal",
  "createdDate": "2018-10-10T19:32:32Z",
  "updatedDate": "2018-12-17T16:46:06Z",
  "dates": {
    "type": "Planned",
    "duration": 43200,
    "start": "2018-10-11T09:00:00",
    "due": "2019-02-13T17:00:00"
  },
  "scope": "WsTask",
  "priority": "5bfa68008000000000003c00"
}
  ]
};

const app = document.getElementById('root');
const container = document.createElement('div');
app.appendChild(container);
testdata.data.forEach(tasks => {
  const card = document.createElement('div');
  card.setAttribute('class', 'card');

  const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  h1.textContent = tasks.title;

  container.appendChild(card);
  card.appendChild(h1);
});
```

```css
.card {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="root">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this, but still no data is coming through. I think in order to make sure that its not my token and authentication that's the issue, I'll create a dummy file with the JSON data and rewrite this. Once I do, I'll come back this afternoon and post results.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I just added a snippet to the answer showing this working without the api request.

Comment: If you aren't certain what is coming back in the response from your request, you can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(testdata))` or use the "Network" portion of the browser developer tools to record the request and response and look at the details there.